# Remove non-alphanumeric characters from start and end of string only

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to clean up some data using a helper exe (C#).

I iterate through each string and I want to remove invalid characters from the start and end of the string i.e. remove the dollar symbols from `$$$helloworld$$$`.

This works fine using this regular expression: `\W`.

However, strings which contain invalid character in the middle should be left alone i.e. `hello$$$$world` is fine and my regular expression should not match this particular string.

So in essence, I am trying to figure out the syntax to match invalid characters at the start and the end of of a string, but leave the strings which contain invalid characters in their body.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

This does it!

```
(^[\W_]*)|([\W_]*$)
```

This `regex` says match zero or more non word characters at the start(`^`) or(`|`) at the end(`$`)

Comment: Watch out though: using `\W` will ignore underscores as well as alphanumerics, so something like *"_helloworld_"* would remain unchanged. If that presents a problem for the OP then they could use something like `[^\W_]` instead of plain `\W`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
^\W+|\W+$
```

`^` and `$` are anchors to the beginning and end of the string respectively.  The `|` in the middle is an OR, so this regex means "either match one or more non-word characters at the start of the string, or match one or more non-word characters at the end of the string".

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ to match the start of string, and $ to match the end of string. [C# Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
 (^[^\w]*)|([^\w]*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ^ to match 'beginning of line' and $ to match 'end of line', i.e. you code should match and remove ^\W* and \W*$